Command transparent already defined
When I try to create my pdf with the code below and the command pdflatex --shell-escape latex.tex on linux :
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
       
\title{Formulaire de mathématique}
\date{ Mai 2024}
\author{mnekkach}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
      
      
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\section{Les identites remarquables}
\subsection{Formules}
$(a + b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$\\
$(a - b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$\\
$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$
\newpage

\section{Calcul de surfaces de formes usuelles}
\subsection{Le carré}

\end{document}

I have the error message :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./latex.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/a4wide/a4wide.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntgclass/a4.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/svg/svg.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/transparent/transparent.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/transparent/transparent-nometadata.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3opacity/l3opacity.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))

! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\transparent' already defined!

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.53       }
            
? 

! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\texttransparent' already defined!

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.62   }
        
? 
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (./latex.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./latex.toc) [2] [3] (./svg-inkscape/square_svg-tex.pdf_tex) [4 <./svg-inkscap
e/square_svg-tex.pdf>] (./latex.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr17.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.
pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on latex.pdf (4 pages, 59428 bytes).
Transcript written on latex.log.

Can someone help me understand the error message and what I can do to solve it?

The line numbers makes the code not compile. So can you please remove them? Additionally the example uses an external file we do not have. So if the file is not needed to reproduce the error, you should also remove it.

If I remove the line numbers and \includesvg{square}, I cannot reproduce the issue with an up-to-date TeX Live. So maybe an upgrade to TeX Live 2024 would help. (Or you should show a real minimal working example to make the problem reproducible.)

adding the line numbers makes it harder to test but your example does not give that error in texlive 2023 or texlive 2024, please show the log file  not the terminal output, so that version numbers are shown

I tested on overleaf and get no errors in texlive 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, as well as testing 2024 locally

The terminal output you show is clearly not from the example code you give.

My counting may be off, but your log file appears to indicate that you \usepackage{xcolor,transparent} after you \usepackage{svg}.  But even doing that and selecting TeXLive 2020 (also indicated by the log), I don't get an error.  Please post the minimal code needed to get the error you claim, as well the error message itself.  And copy/paste your code.

Finally, I uninstalled the 2020 version and reinstalled the 2024 version, and the error message no longer appears. Thank you all for your responses.

In your log you have
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/svg/svg.sty

which is completely wrong: latex/graphics is part of the core "required" latex distribution and does not have an svg subdirectory (or any subdirectory at all.)
That is presumably a local incorrectly installed addition that is breaking the rest of the code.
There is a contributed svg.sty in standard texlive distributions but it does not install under latex/graphics. The terminal should show:
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntgclass/a4.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svg/svg.sty

Delete (or move) the locally installed latex/graphics/svg/svg.sty and rerun mktexlsr to rebuld the file database.
You probably have a second svg.sty installed under latex/svg that should work without error.

You have not shown the log file only the terminal output, the log will have more information including package version strings, so texlive 2023 for example will log
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svg/svg.sty
Package: svg 2020/11/26 v2.02k (include SVG pictures)


I think the problem came from the svg as you say, because I downloaded and copied it myself to this location: latex/graphics.

@mnekkach never install by hand under the standard tree, you will break latex doing that. If you need to install a package by hand install it under ~/texmf or under texmf-local not texmf-dist  that would apply even if you had installed the standard file but this is some different file of the same name.

@mnekkach And on Linux, you should never install anything by hand into the directories managed by your distro's package manager, such as /usr/share. You shouldn't even install standard TeX there unless it is packaged by your distribution and installed by your package manager.

@cfr I am new to LaTeX and I don't know how to install packages. On the CTAN website, it is not explained how to install a package, or maybe I didn't search well.

@mnekkach I'm not talking about LaTeX. Assuming you're using Linux or something like FreeBSD, you shouldn't install any software or files into directories such as /usr/share, /usr/lib etc. because those are managed by your package manager e.g. pacman, apt, dnf or whatever your distro uses. This has zero to do with TeX. There are much worse things than breaking your TeX installation.

@mnekkach you should almost never need to install from ctan, svg package is in texlive so you probably have it already and if not you should use the version in texlive which you can get by apt install texlive-full package.
